# macのjad実行時に"Bad CPU type in executable"が発生する

Tags: java, macos

Macでjadを実行したときに **"Bad CPU type in executable"** が発生しました。
CPUはintelで、intelのjadをbrewでインストールしています。
以前は動いていたのでOSのバージョンアップにより発生したのかと思います。
エラー発生後に再インストールも試みましたが現象は変わりません。
OSは、Catalina, Big Surで発生しました。これは別々な筐体なので再現性あるかと思い質問させていただきました。

```
==> Downloading https://varaneckas.com/jad/jad158g.mac.intel.zip
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing Cask jad
==> Linking Binary 'jad' to '/usr/local/bin/jad'
==> Linking Manpage 'jad.1' to '/usr/local/share/man/man1/jad.1'
  jad was successfully installed!
chappie:flask_sv_git kaoru$ jad
-bash: /usr/local/bin/jad: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Comment: ファイルの日付を見ると2006/07/03でとても古く、この記事 [【Android】APKをデコンパイルしてみる](https://qiita.com/maika_kamada/items/904e842c691e4a66e4a8) だと32bitアプリのようなので、Catalina以後では使えないのでは？

Comment: 解決しました。64bit版のjadxを使う。
こちらも brewでインストールできました。

Comment: 情報共有のために自己回答＆自己解決でもしておいてください。